# translating model attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation, pluralize

I got the following problem with my rails application:
I want to translate some model attributes like this, so that they show up correctly in the validation error messages for example.

```
de:
  activerecord:
    models:
      account:
        attributes:
          email:
            one: 'Email'
            other: 'Emails'
```

Now in the rails console I can check

```
I18n.t 'activerecord.models.account.attributes.email', count: 1
```

which returns "Email" and everything seems to be fine.

But in if I go to the browser and post a form, I get the error

```
I18n::InvalidPluralizationData in AccountsController#create
translation data {:attributes=>{:email=>{:one=>"Email", :other=>"Emails"}}} can not be used with :count => 1
```

How can I resolve this? What translation data does rails expect to get?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Model names and Attribute names both have their own i18n scope.

Try

```
activerecord.attributes.account.email
```

instead of

```
activerecord.models.account.attributes.email
```

(and adjust your yaml file accordingly).

See also the handy [Rails Guide on the I18n API](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rails helper method:

```
Model.human_attribute_name(attribute)
```

Your translation yaml just look like so:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    model_name:
      attributes:
        attribute: attribute name
```